# SQL Server: How to select top rows of a group based on value of the column of that group?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables like below.

## table 1

```
id rem   
1   2
2   1
```

## table 2

```
id value
1   abc
1   xyz
1   mno
2   mnk
2   mjd
```

EDIT:

```
#output
id value
1  abc
1  xyz
2  mnk
```

What i want to do is select top 2 rows of table2 with id one as rem value is 2 for id 1 and top 1 row with id 2 as its rem value is 1 and so on. I am using MS sqlserver 2012 My whole scenario is more complex than this. Please help.
Thank you.
EDIT : I know that i should have given what i have done and how i am doing it but for this particular part i don't have idea for starting. I could do this by using while loop for each unique id but i want to do it in one go if possible.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: What have you tried, exactly which part do you have problems with?

Comment: I am writing stored procedure and its business is huge. I cannot explain all the business here. Question i asked is very simplified version of my problem. If i could get help that will be great help. I didn't came here without any research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no specification of which values you get, unless you include an `order by`.

For this purpose, I would go with `row_number()`:

```
select t2.*
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t2.seqnum <= t1.rem;
```

Note:  The `order by id` in the windows clause should be based on *which* rows you want.  If you don't care which rows, then `order by id` or `order by (select null)` is fine.

Comment: thanks for quick response. I will let you know as soon as possible after i use it in my stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE (id INT, rem INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES (1,   2), (2,   1)

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE (id INT, value VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES  (1,   'abc'), (1,   'xyz'),
(1,   'mno'), (2,   'mnk'), (2,   'mjd')

SELECT * FROM @tbl1 -- your table 1
SELECT * FROM @tbl2 -- your table 2

SELECT id,value,rem FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.ID ORDER BY T.ID) rowid,
T.id,T.value,F.rem FROM  @tbl2 T LEFT JOIN @tbl1 F ON T.id = F.id ) A WHERE rowid = 1 
-- your required output
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: And out put from your query is :
id value rem
1  abc   2 
2    mnk 1